# Perturbed identity in bilinear form

Tags: matrices

If I have a bilinear form $$x^TAy,$$ which I then compare to a bilinear form $$x^T(I-uu^T)^TA(I-vv^T)y,$$ where $||u||_2 = ||v||_2 = 1$, do there exist simple conditions such that the second form is bounded by the first? $A$ can be assumed to be PSD, if it helps.

My vague intuition is that because $(I-uu^T)$ is still PSD but upper bounded by the identity these conditions should exist, but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: "the second form is bounded by the first" What exactly do you mean by this?